# How to ensure NServiceBus runs in sequence

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

We have a requirement for all our messages to be processed in sequence. I don't mean in terms of a Saga but that each message is processed as it is picked off the bus. If a message errors we expect that the process will halt processing other messages until the errored message has reached its retry limit.

Is there anyway that NServiceBus can handle such a requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, but would having a combination of setting NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" and just one handler process do this for you?

That way only one message will be processed at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As I know msmq do not garantee right sequence delivery out of transaction.